# Mounting Iphone as a disk

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa

I have a small application which runs on osx and iphone. I am trying to extend my osx application which should be able to detect when iphone is plugged in and able to transfer files to desktop application.

Is there a driver required / any user mode code to mount iphone on OSX.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you talking about jailbroken iphone, because otherwise it's impossible.

Comment: I use a program called phone disk it works great

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not let you transfer files directly, however they give you a way to transfer files through iTunes.  I found [this link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/49101/transfer-filedata-via-itunes-to-the-app).

Comment: There is a way, I am just not sure if apple would like it.  Also, using iTunes will be far easier.